# Selenium webscraping TimeoutException with stacktrace of pointers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently using selenium to web-scrape for articles on the RSC corpus. I keep running into an error due to the line:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.capsule.capsule--article')))
```

I have tried both EC.presence_of_element_located and EC.visibility_of_element_located, and both give me the same TimeoutException error. I am not sure what else I can try to get rid of the TimeoutException, as the CSS selector is correct, and the URL properly loads the query on RSC.

Here is my stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rsc.py", line 40, in <module>
    main(url, query, page, location)
  File "rsc.py", line 22, in main
    dois = scraper.get_doi(query=query, page=page)
  File "/home/ssarrouf/Documents/GitHub/WaterRemediationParser/batterydataextractor-main/batterydataextractor/scrape/rsc.py", line 62, in get_doi
    _ = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.capsule.capsule--article')))
  File "/home/ssarrouf/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55e10fae5d93 <unknown>
#1 0x55e10f8b42d7 <unknown>
#2 0x55e10f8f0caa <unknown>
#3 0x55e10f8f0db1 <unknown>
#4 0x55e10f92e8f4 <unknown>
#5 0x55e10f91461d <unknown>
#6 0x55e10f92c619 <unknown>
#7 0x55e10f914353 <unknown>
#8 0x55e10f8e3e40 <unknown>
#9 0x55e10f8e5038 <unknown>
#10 0x55e10fb398be <unknown>
#11 0x55e10fb3d8f0 <unknown>
#12 0x55e10fb1df90 <unknown>
#13 0x55e10fb3eb7d <unknown>
#14 0x55e10fb0f578 <unknown>
#15 0x55e10fb63348 <unknown>
#16 0x55e10fb634d6 <unknown>
#17 0x55e10fb7d341 <unknown>
#18 0x7f0fad5a9b43 <unknown>
```

My code in the "get_doi" method:

```
def get_doi(self, query, page):
      """
        Get a list of dois from query massages and the exact page.
        :param query: the query text (e.g. battery materials)
        :param page: the number of page
        :return: a list of dois of the relevant query text and page.
        """
        
        if self.driver is None:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        else:
            driver = self.driver

        if self.url is None:
            url = "http://pubs.rsc.org/en/results?searchtext="
            url = url + query
        else:
            url = self.url
        driver.get(url)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, self.max_wait_time)
        # To make sure we don't overload the server
        sleep(1)
        next_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class^=paging__btn]")))[1]
        page_string = """document.querySelectorAll("a[class^=paging__btn]")[1].setAttribute("data-pageno", \""""\
                      + str(page) + """\")"""
        driver.execute_script(page_string)
        next_button.click()
        sleep(1)
        _ = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.capsule.capsule--article')))
        doi_lists = driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'https://doi.org')
        dois = [doi.text for doi in doi_lists]
        return dois
```

My code for downloading the articles:

```
    def download_doi(self, doi, file_location):
    """
    Download the html paper of the doi
    :param doi: doi of the paper
    :param file_location: the saving location
    :return:
    """
    doi = doi.split("org/")[-1]
    r = requests.get('http://doi.org/' + doi, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    result = re.findall(r'https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/.*?"', r.text)
    url = result[0][:-1]
    web_content = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}).content

    result = self.get_rsc_abstract(web_content)
    exact_date = result['date'].split("/")
    doi = result['doi'].replace("/", "_")
    if len(exact_date) == 3:
        name = exact_date[0] + exact_date[1] + exact_date[2] + '_' + doi
    else:
        name = result['online_date'].replace("/", "") + '_' + doi

    with open(file_location + name + '.html', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(web_content)
    return
```

And the main method I am calling for the web-scraping:

```
def main(url, query, page, file_location):
    """
    RSC web-scraper runner
    :param url: the scraping url (or default)
    :param query: query text (e.g. battery materials)
    :param page: the page number of the query pages
    :param file_location: saving location
    :return:
    """
    scraper = RSCWebScraper(url=url)
    dois = scraper.get_doi(query=query, page=page)
    for doi in dois:
        try:
            scraper.download_doi(doi, file_location)
        # Some papers don't have html access
        except:
            continue
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Download papers within a certain date range
    url = "https://pubs.rsc.org/en/results/all?Category=All&AllText=water%20remediation&IncludeReference=false&Select" \
          "Journal=false&DateRange=true&SelectDate=true&DateToYear={}&DateFromYear={}&DateFromMonth={}&DateTo" \
          "Month={}&PriceCode=False&OpenAccess=false".format("2022", "2021", "06", "01")
    query = "water remediation"
    location = r"/home/ssarrouf/Documents/webscrape/to_date_papers/rsc/"
    for page in range(1, 120):
        main(url, query, page, location)
```

Changing the method for

````
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.capsule.capsule--article')))

``` did not give me any results, and I also changed the query / url text to various months and years to ensure that the request was properly loading. These did nothing and I got TimeoutExceptions for each attempt.
````

Comment: An example _query_?

Comment: few questions (1) is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgGeP.png) the page you want to scrape? (2) what value is assigned to `max_wait_time`? (3) why you run `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.capsule.capsule--article')))` if you then don't use it? Isn't better to remove that line and instead do `doi_list = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'https://doi.org')))`? Anyway, I tried both commands and they work

Comment: @soundwave Yes, that is the page I want to scrape! And max_wait_time is set as 30. And you're saying that when you ran both commands papers downloaded for you? Every time I run the code my chrome window just refreshes and quits and continues to do this until I get a TimeoutException.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Hi! The query is the keywords that I am using to search the RSC page, in this case it is 'water remediation'.

Comment: what happens if you run this two commands? `driver.get('http://pubs.rsc.org/en/results?searchtext=water%20remediation'); WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.capsule.capsule--article')))`

Comment: @soundwave I get a TimeoutException -- driver.get('http://pubs.rsc.org/en/results?searchtext=water%20remediation');  did not work for me because I have a list dependent on the find_elements method for downloading the dois, so I changed the two lines to: 
doi_lists = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.capsule.capsule--article')))

doi_lists = driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'https://doi.org')

And I get a TimeoutException with a stack of unknown pointers as shown above

Comment: @soundwave I also added the code I have for downloading the doi links!

Comment: What does "driver.get('pubs.rsc.org/en/results?searchtext=water%20remediation') did not work for me because I have a list dependent on the find_elements method for downloading the dois" mean??